# iOS: Presenting a UIViewController modally (form sheet/page sheet) over splitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController (is the rootViewController) 
and a UIViewController, vc1.

I'm trying to present vc1 over my split view controller from the MasterViewController part:

```
vc1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this raises an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active 
controller <MasterViewController: 0x8c5dd30>.'
```

...and crashes.

Tried this:

```
[self.splitViewController presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This raises an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason:'Application tried to present modally an active 
controller <UISplitViewController:0x8c7e3a0>.'
```

**However, if i try it with the interface builder (segues), it works.**

How do i present a view controller, modally (as pages sheet or form sheet), over a split view controller, programmatically?

Comment: Is vc1 in a UINavigationController?

Comment: @cortez No, its seperate.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the DetailView controller to show it. Something like this I suppose.

```
DetailVC *detailVC = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[detailVC presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I suppose the issue is that your master is presenting a detail view and that's why it can't present anything else, so you ask the detail view to do it for you.